# google maps geocode: I get a new API key and it claims it's invalid

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, api-key

I have a geocode library (makeKML.pm at MarginalHacks.com) which uses the Google Maps geocode API.  It has stopped working because it was using v2 requests, so I've switched to v3, and I'm told my API key is invalid.  So I login to their disastrously confusing cloud console and finally figure out how to make a new server API key.  Again I try a request with the new key:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=659+Valencia+St%2C+San+Francisco+CA&key=<<<my new API key here>>>
```

I keep getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
 <error_message>The provided API key is invalid.</error_message>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Any thoughts on what's going on, or how I can ensure that I'm using the right type of API key?  I've turned on the Google Maps Geocode API in the cloud console and registered a new web app which is where I'm getting the server key I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works [without a key](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=659+Valencia+St%2C+San+Francisco+CA)

There is no [key parameter to the Google Maps Geocoding Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests); the documentation does state: "Maps API for Business users must include valid client and signature parameters with their Geocoding requests", but that is additional cost (a contract with Google), and not a "key".

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't realize they had removed the need for an API key.  An interesting choice, but it makes my software easier.  :)

Thanks much and you've been upvoted!

Comment: This answer isn't actually correct. There is a key parameter, it's just optional now. And sometimes it's actually very useful if you want to keep track of your usage, get emails when you go over limit, etc. So I don't know the answer to the original poster's question, but this isn't really it. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key

Comment: There was no key parameter (optional or otherwise) at the time the question was originally answered, it has since been added.

Comment: Now (In 2024) we need an API Key for geocoding requests using Google Maps API